# Looking for an efficient way to query "perldelta"s for news

Tags: linux, perl, documentation

A common problem I have with Perl is this:
I want to find out at *which release* some feature had been introduced.

There were several "perldelta" manual pages (one for each release), but I'm looking for an efficient ways to query those.
Unfortunately recent distributions from SUSE seem to ship only the current "perldelta" manual page (it seems).

```text
> man -k perldelta
perldelta (1)        - what is new for perl v5.26.1
```

In fact, there are many pages shipped:

```text
> rpm -ql perl-doc |grep delta
...
usr/share/man/man1/perl5004delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5005delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5100delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5101delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5120delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5121delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5122delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5123delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5124delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5125delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5140delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5141delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5142delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5143delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5144delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5160delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5161delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5162delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5163delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5180delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5181delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5182delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5184delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5200delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5201delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5202delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5203delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5220delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5221delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5222delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5223delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5224delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5240delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5241delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5242delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5260delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl5261delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl561delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl56delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl581delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl582delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl583delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl584delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl585delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl586delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl587delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl588delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl589delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perl58delta.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/perldelta.1.gz
```

To read the specification of a function, I can use `perldoc -f function`, but that does not tell me in which release a feature was introduced.

Any clever ideas?

Comment: Copy the manpages somewhere else, decompress them using `gunzip` and then use `grep`?

Comment: I could use `zgrep` instead, but still grep just knows about words, not structure. For example: `grep "local sub" /usr/lib/perl5/5.26.1/pod/perl*delta.pod`